# Why can't the Galaxy Note 4 capture 4K Pictures and only Videos despite having that 4K screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

Why is it that, despite having a resolution of 2560×1440, the note 4 can't capture 4K pictures?

Comment: The screen doesn't take pictures, the camera is separate hardware.

Comment: 2560x1440 isn't a 4k screen: that would be 3840x2160

Answer (score 3):

According to Samsung's specification, the Note 4 supports UHD 4K video (3840 x 2160 pixels) @30 fps and pictures up to 16 megapixel (a little bit (4MP) more than 4K).

So you can actually record 4K videos and pictures, but note that they have to follow the standards (pictures are usually 4:3 or 3:2 and videos 16:9). That's it.